# View webdriver tests running on EC2

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, chrome, aws, headless

I have my selenium webdriver tests on EC2.  Chrome --headless flag is on and job is started from Jenkins. Is there a way to watch the live UI tests on the browser window via a VNC connection from my local machine like how it's done on Selenium GRID?

I do not want to use Selenium Grid at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues you need to think about;

1. You are running on headless mode, so there should be no visible Chrome window. You may need to disable it.
2. If the Jenkins initiated the job; you can see the Chrome window, only if you VNC with Jenkins user, not another account/user.

Comment: I tried VNC option witout headless flag and here's where I am stuck at now. Any help would be really appreciated.  Here's a detailed explanation of my issue.    https://stackoverflow.com/q/63935935/4113833

Comment: On the code side, I'm using webdriver as driver=new ChromeDriver (path): and not remotedriver(EC2 IP)/wd/hud. Was thinking of using remotedriver as next debugging step.  *Please excuse the syntax, commenting from my phone.

Comment: I see that you figured out.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your comment, @Turicia. Turning off headless mode suggestion helped.